# Deploy 1 single ARM template containing multiple resources or deploy separate resources in parallel?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Anyone knows if there are advantages or disadvantages of running parallel ARM deployments of different resources or just combining them in one single ARM deployment.

Comment: I had answered, but now I'm not sure if I answered the right question.. I guess you mean why would you want to do `deploy.json` and within it, run a deployment of `deploy-1.json` and `deploy-2.json`? If that's the case, then it's about re-using the same template for similar resources, and to reduce complexity in the main template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An early step of an ARM deployment is to check if the resources defined in the template depend on each other.
If some resources depend on each other, dependent resources will be deployed sequentially, resources with no depency link will be deployed in paralell.

If your Azure resources contains no dependency links, using one big template or several templates will give the same result (from a deployment point of view).

However using several templates will give you the following benefits :

1. Maintainability
2. Share
3. Modularity
4. Testability

(1) JSON format is really verbose, ARM templates can grow quickly and templates become hard to understand and to maintain even without a big complexity.

(2) When working in teams, each team do not need to manage all the Azure resources. Using several templates can help teams to focus only on specific parts of the target Azure infrastructure. 
For example a "Data" team may not need to use a template wich contains Databases, Web Apps and Virtual Machine resources : the team just need to be able to manage Databases Resources.

(3) Using sereval templates will help you to see your infrastructure as a set of components that can be deployed together or individually. Besides each smaller template can be re-used easily in differents projects.

(4) Smaller templates will be easier to test than a unique big template.